# Airtel 4g network not working on certain apps

Tags: 4g, vivo

So I am using Vivo V7 on an airtel 4g data connection and every time I try to open apps like swiggy or foodpanda I get a message saying "there was a problem" "please try again later. However when I open these apps on a wifi they work fine. What is going wrong here??

Answer (score 0):

It may cause due to of bad connection low signals or due to data roaming is off.

Steps to fix step:-

1. Go to settings and find cellular settings.
2. Open them and turn on data roaming.
3. Now change network mode 4G or LTE only depends to various device.
4. Save them turn of data if on.
5. Reboot your device.
6. Turn on data might fix it.

   **If above-mentioned didn't work go to step 3 and select 3G Only mode and perfom other steps same as mentioned**

Answer (score 0):

Simple: Go to APN settings and set APN protocol to IPV4 only from IPV4/IPV6 and save.